# Making python-based .exe file accessible to anyone

Tags: repository, language-agnostic, executable

I have used Spyder (Anaconda) to generate a Python GUI App. The app can browse & load any time series csv file on the user's pc, perform few statistical tests and print the results on to a txt file and save it to the user's desktop screen.

**Is it possible to upload the executable file on to any repository so that others could try it out.** For example, Google Earth Engine based apps can be easily shared via a link and anyone with that link can access the app. Similarly, is there anything for my case ?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer your looking for,

But you can upload .exe to Google drive and share it. So anyone could download it from the link generated.

> File types: Users can upload any type of file, including executables
> (for example, .exe or .vbs) and compressed files.
> [source](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172541?hl=en)